# Problems with JQuery Mobile on IPhone PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, ios-simulator

I am writing my first cross-platform mobile application with the PhoneGap.

In PhoneGap's site I found that JQuery Mobile is the most usefull for UI in PhoneGap. Then i found some tutorials for JQuery(http://devgrow.com/mobile-web-dev-using-jquery-mobile). they are ok in the web browsers, but when i start it on IPhone Simulator JQuery doesnt work.

Why? How can i solve this problem.

[image: browser and iphone]

UPD: I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
```

like in tutorial

Comment: are u opening it in browser? or in an app?

Comment: @ghostCoder - both, browser and app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the below files in your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.js"></script>
```

**Edit:**
I checked your tutorial link,it been mentioned

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
```

May be you DOM is generated before your JQuery file are loaded. So I suggest you to download them  locally into your JS folder and refer as I mentioned in the above

Comment: I suggest you to download the JQuery js and css locally and then refer to them. You can download them from here http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: No, you DOM is not loaded before the script tags are finished being downloaded and evaluated. Script tags in the head tag are blocking. They prevent the body tag from being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I went to http://devgrow.com/examples/jquerymobile/ the iOS Simulator and it works fine.

Also, I tried to copy the source of this webpage, to paste it the index.html page oh e PhoneGap Project (with adding a link to phonegap.js) and it works fine.

Did you also try these steps ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not too late to answer,

I had this problem & the reason is that phonegap does not load files outside of its approved domains.

So I went over to phonegap.plist or cordova.plist & added the hosts in 'ExternalHost' section array.

It worked out well,

Of course, the only way to detect this is to see the xcode messages area & see something with "whitelist"

Hope it helps